# How to test a method which is resolving a promise and then changing state in React?

Tags: reactjs, testing, promise, jestjs, enzyme

I need to test that when button is clicked and after promise resolve
`state.message === 'loggedIn successfully'`

```js
class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.onLoginClick = this.onLoginClick.bind(this); 
    }

    fetchLogin() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            reollve({ success: true });
        })
    }

    onLoginClick() {
        let that = this;
        fetchLogin().then(function ({ success }) {
            success ?
                that.setState({ message: 'loggedIn successfully' }) :
                that.setState({ message: 'Fail' });

        })
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <button onClick={this.onLoginClick}></button>
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are aware of jest `simulate` in order to simulate your click ( if not then [simulate](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html))

You should be able to use jest async/await or promises with jest, [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html) is the link to the official doc

It should be something like this :

```
it('works with async/await and resolves', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Login />);

  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click'); 

  await expect(wrapper.state().message).resolves.toEqual('loggedIn successfully');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing a test on a promise, you should wait for the function triggered by the button to execute before you can make the assertion (thus the `await`).
The code below should work for you case:

```
it('should change state on successful login', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Login  />);

    await wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

    expect(wrapper.state().message).toEqual("loggedIn successfully");
  });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde thanks for the feedback, I added a short explanation to hopefully make the answer more clear.